# If something is temporally and spatially vague, then can it be individuated by its absence?

Tags: existence, death, vagueness, nothingness, spacetime

### 1 If something is temporally and spatially vague, then can it become nothing?

I am thinking that **it cannot be entirely individuated from its absence while it exists, because e.g. the space where it borderline extends to is vague**. It seems intuitive that such a thing, if it existed, would never become entirely absent, but it's a bold claim. What about Everest sometime recently? Surely mountains fall. So, the answer there is yes.

### 2 Can it be individuated by its absence?

As death is meant to do to us ("no-one can die my death for me")? I think that this is similar to asking whether nothingness (an absence or gap, etc.) can be of vague tokens, becasue tokens are individual things in space and time. Again yes, no real worries thinking of this. There is a gap to some vague places. But you would think not necessarily one that individuates it. Depending on where the gap is, it could be vague whether it exists in the place or the place it is vague with, vague whether it belongs to it alone. So no, *not if we are talking a complete absence*?

### 3 What about something that is merely spatially vague?

Can something that is not temporally vague be entirely individuated by its complete absence? I would ***suppose*** yes, insofar as then there could be a sharp time at which it and it alone begins to not exist. Even without temporal vagueness it is difficult to think of compositionally vague things being gradually eliminated into nothing, but easy enough to assert that from today I have no bald friends, especially if there were no borderline cases of baldness to them.

Can anyone at least think of a counterexample to 2?

---

Spatially vague: vague where it is in space, such as Everest

Temprorally vague: vague when it exists

Individuated: determine what thing we are talking about (so e.g. to individuate an object it's not like we have to state its exact colour, but we do need to distinguish it from similar objects and from its environment etc.)

Comment: any feedback on the downcote?

Comment: By "become nothing" do you mean "cease to exist"? Things don't cease to exist by becoming nothing, but by the broader processes that they described changing states. When you snuff out a candle, we observe that the flame no longer exists, but what has been lost is only the *state of being lit*. The air, the fuel, the wick, the soot, and the energy are all still there.

Comment: What is a "spatiotemporally vague thing"? Vagueness, as typically used, is not a property of things, it is a property of predicates, see [Sorites](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sorites-paradox). A thing can be vaguely a mountain because "is a mountain" is vague, but there is nothing vague about the thing itself. So what exactly are you trying to "individuate"? Draw a crisp boundary between "is present" and "is absent"? That there is no such boundary is just the definition of "vague". 2 is obscure. Is the question whether "is completely absent" can be defined so as not to be vague?

Comment: @Conifold what sort of question are you asking me here? i have seen the phrase temporally vague (e.g.)

Comment: Seen it where and applied to what? Maybe give a link or quote. It is unclear what you are asking, probably because "vague" and "individuated" are used in some personal sense.

Comment: so you need me to prove to you @Conifold that i am not using a neologism disguised as a philosophical term that others use? hardly seems reasonable

Comment: maybe "bceome" is the wrong word for some people, but it seems readily understood, and i don't see any need for metaphysical baggage here @gs

Comment: "bceome" is definitely a wrong word.

Comment: that's sharp of you @MarcoOcram

Comment: You now have two delete votes for being unclear. Maybe instead of being defensive, you should cooperate with the people trying to help you make it clearer.

Comment: i have tried @DavidGudeman hope it isn't deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be individuated, but vaguely. Consider the sounds made by a crowd at a football match. The nature and intensity of the sound varies as the match progresses. At times there may be unmistakeable crescendos- as for example, in that famous incident at Wembley in '66 when I made my legendary dash along the entire length of the field, dodging opponent after opponent to... sorry, I was distracted for a moment. Where was I? Oh, yes, there may be an unmistakeable crescendo, even though you would not be able to say exactly when or where it started or ended. An especially loud or prolonged roar might even provoke a reference from the retired footballer overpaid by the BBC for commenting on the match, as might the absence of an enthusiastic response during a lull in the action, so it seems clear that temporal and spatial vagueness does not rule out the possibility of a form of individuation.

You might argue that the roar of a crowd is not an object, but just a dynamic arrangement of molecules. True, but then Everest is just a dynamic arrangement of molecules- albeit a more stable one.

Comment: can anything be vaguely individuated? i thought determination was a type of specification, something like that?

Comment: i suppose what you mean is that it cannot be *absolutely* individuated by its absence. that makes sense, though i still think it a little creepy to think that my death doesn't completely individuate my dasein (you can die my death a little for me)

Comment: @bloke Whose what-now? I think you mean the *cessation* of *that thing over there*. Just *knowing it's a death* requires knowing more than where it isn't, and knowing that it's *your* death, and not, say, a cabbage's death, requires knowing a great deal about more than that.

Comment: i feel that you are not engaging with what i am trying to say, and that is confusing me @gs there are many ways of talking about "death"

Comment: I am sure that on reflection you will realise that there are countless things that can be individuated but only in a vague way. Consider the Nile, for example, which is an individual river. Where, exactly, is the boundary of the Nile? Where are the dividing lines between the Nile and it many tributaries?

Comment: Some physicists would argue that the molecules in the Everest are part of the Everest, whereas the molecules in the air are only a support for the sound wave, and not part of the sound. I'm not saying that sound isn't a thing, I'm just saying it's debatable whether air molecules are part of that thing.

Comment: @Stef it's all too confusing for me, that's for sure!

Answer (score 0):

**1. If something is temporally and spatially vague, then can it become nothing?**

Yes. For example, a cloud is a temporally and spatially vague object. It does not have sharp boundaries in time or space. However, clouds can dissipate and disappear.

Another example is a mountain. Mountains are not always temporally and spatially vague, but they can be. For example, a mountain that is eroding may have vague boundaries. And if the mountain erodes completely, then it will become nothing.

**2. Can something that is temporally and spatially vague be individuated by its absence?**

It is not clear to me what it means for something to be individuated by its absence.

Maybe one way to think about individuation is to think about it in terms of identity. If two things are identical, then they are the same thing. And if two things are not identical, then they are different things. So, if something is individuated by its absence, then it must be the case that its absence is identical to it. But this seems strange. How can something be identical to its absence?

We can also think about it in terms of properties. If two things have all of the same properties, then they are the same thing. And if two things do not have all of the same properties, then they are different things.

So, if something is individuated by its absence, then it must be the case that its absence has all of the same properties as it does. But this also seems weird. How can something have all of the same properties as its absence?

**3. What about something that is merely spatially vague? Can something that is not temporally vague be entirely individuated by its complete absence?**

A hole is a spatially vague object. It does not have sharp boundaries in space. However, a hole can be filled in, and then it will cease to exist.

Another example is a shadow. Shadows are not always spatially vague, but they can be. For example, the shadow of a tree on a cloudy day may have vague boundaries. And if the sun goes behind the clouds, then the shadow will disappear.

Counterexample to 2:

How about a gap in a wall?

A gap in a wall is a temporally and spatially vague object. It does not have sharp boundaries in time or space. However, it seems like a gap in a wall could be individuated by its absence. If the gap were to be filled in, then it would cease to exist.

Comment: -1 cos you seem to have ignored where i made it clear what individuation is. you also need to show that a gap in a wall is temporally vague, that what it is, is completely determined by being filled (how so?), etc

Comment: OMG -1! I don't give a sh*t, sorry. I am not farming imaginable points here. :)

Comment: I am sharing my answers and reasoning. Not all of them may be perfect. I am just amused by the value you probably assign to some marks here as you specifically say you downvoted me. Such a cute infantile projection. :)

Comment: no it's called a website, with feedback and interaction etc.. are all gaps vague in every way? do you really think that a filled gap is identical to an open one? etc.

Comment: ps downvoting me for downvoting you is a really annoying tit-for-tat "philosophy". maybe it is indicative of what you want to be, idk..